# Why doesn't Facebook like button and Twitter tweet button align on my website?

Tags: css

As seen below "Share this awesome read: " at the end of the article.

I've tried various CSS changes, but can't get it to align.

http://poachedmag.com/2012/11/01/laneway-festival-singapore-line-up-released/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your css and try again:

```
div.share iframe.twitter-share-button { position: relative; top:3px; }
```

Comment: neater than mine... go for that, i think i might too, plus would need the container div to be narrowed to keep the buttons centered

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up putting each in their own div with the style property `float:left` and for the twitter holder, I added `margin-top:3px` and that seemed to be enough to make it line up nicely

```
<div style="float:left">
    <!-- FACEBOOK BUTTON -->
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:3px">
    <!-- TWITTER BUTTON -->
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```